# insert in to two table using one query inner join

Tags: mysql, insert, inner-join

I have two tables. One is `user_info` and the other is `user_login`. I want to insert data into both these tables in one query using an inner join. The data comes from user registration.

My login table:

```
user_id(pk) user_name  user_password
 1           jinesh     secret
 2           mahesh     secret
```

My info table:

```
user_id(fk) name      address   phno
   1        jinesh n  banglore  9845***
   2        mahesh m  chennai   7345**
```

Comment: You can't insert into multiple tables with a single query.  You can however combine multiple queries into a single transaction, if you're trying to attain ACID compliance.

Comment: You can't insert data into multiple tables with one query

Comment: you can do it. You have to seperate the querys with ;

Comment: @RafaelShkembi then that's two queries.

Comment: @moopet yes 2 queries in one statement

Comment: @RafaelShkembi The question explicitly asks for one query.

Comment: @moopet that's imposible ;)

Comment: @RafaelShkembi yes - so the answer is clearly not "you can do it". Presumably the question exists because Ranjith wants to effect both inserts simultaneously rather than sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make one query to `insert` values in `two tables`

However if you want to have the two querys in only one statement then
this can be done if you seperate the statements with `;`

```
$query = "insert into table_1 (data1, data2) values ('value1', 'value2');insert into table_2 (data1,data2) values ('value1', 'value2')";
```

Comment: How about the `user_id(p)` & `user_id(fk)` ? Will it insert automatically?

Comment: @jonju what's the problem with those 2? The above query is only a example of the columns and the values. The op has to edit the two queries in his needs

Comment: This exam won't works if the `user_id` is AUTO_INCREMENT. It's better to let people know the Do's and Don't,

Comment: we don't know that, the OP knows. If the OP would tell us then we can fix the 'example'

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `Stored Procedure`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Proc_User` (IN username VARCHAR(225), IN password VARCHAR(255), 
IN uname VARCHAR(255),IN addr VARCHAR(255),IN phno VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
    BEGIN
    -- ERROR or WARNING
    ROLLBACK;
    END;
    START TRANSACTION;  
    DECLARE userid INT;
    INSERT INTO login (user_name,user_password) VALUES(username,password);

    SET userid = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());

    INSERT INTO info(user_id,name,address,phno) 
    VALUES(userid,uname,addr,password);
    COMMIT;
END
```

And to call the Stored Procedure in PHP

```
$proc = mysqli_prepare('CALL Proc_User(?, ?, ?,?,?);');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param('sssss', $username, $password, $name,$address,$phoneno);
mysqli_stmt_execute($proc);
```